# After else statement finish test case

Tags: java, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

Could somenone, please provide me with answer.
Namely, My for loop looks like (it actually founds element which has no atribute **disabled**, but what if all elements are disabled, then I want to finish test and sent message). So how can I rewrite this loop to be **if/else**.

```
        if (disabled == null) {
            dropdown3.selectByValue(option.getAttribute("value"));
            break;
        }
```

Message which I want to show as end of test should be:

> ELement is not enabled, so finishing test

and go directly to

```
driver.close();
```

And finish test.

Comment: please be elaborate

Comment: You can use Boolean operators to check all the elements are disabled or not

Comment: I want add inside **if** case when I have not any element with atribute _disalbled_  and put **else** and sent message with some text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can check for undisabled values

```
if (undisabled =! null) {
    dropdown3.selectByValue(option.getAttribute("value"));
}
else {
    System.out.print("All features are disabled.");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you @Blacklp